# Are strong, retain and assign properties are same in Non-ARC?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, properties

I do see many threads discussing their differences in ARC. Can anyone explain to me the differences under non-ARC environment? Thanks

Comment: `strong` and `retain` are synonyms.

Comment: Curious - why are you coding in MRC?

Comment: @rmaddy these two questions are not entirely same. The point I was addressing is if strong and retain are the same in non-ARC.

Comment: `strong` didn't exist before ARC. If you use it with MRC, it's just a synonym for `retain`.